# Command line tool to merge textfiles , keeping the common content and adding the rest of the content to it

Tags: linux, string, text, diff

I have got a folder with notes on different topics, say `~/notes/topica.txt` `~/notes/topicb.txt` etc... . I have been using them in different computers for some time now so they have diverted their content
So I have now something like

```
@computerA:
cat  ~/notes/topica.txt

Lines added in Computer A

----------
Some common text
```

```
@computerB:
cat  ~/notes/topica.txt

Lines added in Computer B

----------
Some common text
```

I want to be able to merge them in a way that I get

```
cat  ~/notes/topica.txt
Lines added in Computer A

Lines added in Computer B

----------
Some common text
```

I have tried some tools like `diff` but they are really not achieving the objective I want.
Also I need to do it for an entire folder with a bunch of files. (Im alright with doing a bash script)
Thanks for your help